# Eclipse plugin - TFS (Team Explorer Everywhere) not connecting to TFS Repository

Tags: eclipse, tfs, osx-mavericks

I'm running OSX 10.9 Maverick, following a restart I began to see the following message:

"An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing TFS Repository information for https://yourwebsite.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/".
The character '
' is not permitted in server paths."

I've tried removing all traces of Eclipse & Team Explorer Everywhere and re-installing it as a clean-version but the error continues.

Here's a list of files/directories I removed..

1. Users/My-Mac/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Team Foundation/
2. Users/My-Mac/.eclipse
3. Users/My-Mac/Preferences/org.eclipse.platform.ide.plist
4. Users/My-Mac/Documents/Workspace/
5. Users/My-Mac/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.platform.ide/
6. Users/My-Mac/Library/Saved Application State/org.eclipse.platform.ide.savedState
7. Applications/Eclipse

LOG: 
Pastebin of log - http://pastebin.com/XSukZRb2

Comment: This is not likely to be a case of some "dirty file", this is likely a problem parsing something being delivered from the server.  It would be interesting to see where this exception is actually coming from.  You can see more details in `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Team Explorer/12.0/Logs`.

Comment: It generates two logfiles, but both are blank.

`teamexplorer-plugin-2014.07.29-09.21.43.log` and
`teamexplorer-soap-plugin-2014.07.29-09.21.43.log`

Comment: Ugh.  Can you disable mylyn briefly?  It likes to do terrible things to the TEE log files.

Comment: Log available here - http://pastebin.com/XSukZRb2 

Not really giving me more insight, other than the character issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was actually with the machines name!

'My-Mac' contains an hyphin, which seems to cause issues when using TEE. I updated my machine name to MyMac (Preferences -> Sharing -> Update 'Computer Name'). Once the machine name was updated to MyMac, I removed the old Eclipse workspace and added a new one.

TFS loaded correctly this time, no more character issue.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for finding the root cause; what a surprise!  We will look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

I deeply suspect it is another symptom of the TFS/.NET MAX_PATH problem. We have some very long paths in our enlistment and we keep our enlistment roots limited to 12 characters to avoid exceeding the limit. On this Mac, I enlisted to the default eclipse workspace path, like /Users/apple.dev/Documents/workpspace/abcdefgh. When syncing I hit the error. Tried multiple times with the same result. When I mapped to /abcdefgh. the problem went away.

Alex, for your case, it's entirely possible that removing the '-' in your machine name changed the length of a path string and put you under the limit. Hopes this helps you.

PS: Visual Studio / Team Services folks, I'm ex-Microsoft/DevDiv. Feel free to contact me if you have questions or want to try a private drop.